# Convert single non-iterable digit in tuple into a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
a = ((), (), (5, 5, 5), (), (3), (), ())
[list(x) for x in a]
```

Expected output `[[], [], [5, 5, 5], [], [3], [], []]`
but got

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2):

What  you have is not a tuple.

Use `(3,)` instead of `(3)` to create a tuple, otherwise Python thinks it's an expression and returns `3`.

Comment: A common mistake with tuples.  It's not the parentheses that make a tuple, it's the commas.

Comment: I tried [tuple(x) for x in a] but I am still not getting (3,).

Comment: @Toffyraider it's still the same problem; try `tuple(3)` and see what happens.  You need to pass in a sequence and not a single number.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma in (3). The correct code would be:

```
a = ((), (), (5, 5, 5), (), (3,), (), ())
[list(x) for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a judgment statement, like this:

```
a = ((), (), (5, 5, 5), (), (3), (), ())

print(list(map(lambda x: [x] if isinstance(x, (int, float)) else list(x), a)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried
a = ((), (), (5, 5, 5), (), (3), (), ())
[tuple(x) for x in a]

I got TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. Is there a method to convert it to (3,)?

Comment: You can edit your original answer instead of posting another one, specially when it only adds the original error you get.